# (Android) Is there a way to detect when text has been selected in a webview?

Tags: android, webview

In API 11+ when long-pressing on text in a WebView the Contextual Action Bar (CAB) is shown. I don't want to override the existing menu items so implementing my own ActionMode.Callback isn't the correct answer. I just want to know when the default CAB is shown so that I know text selection has begun that way I can lock scrolling on the WebView. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm wanting to hide my header bar when the CAB is shown.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know when the default CAB is on screen, you can check for it's existence after an ACTION_UP:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
WebView mWebView;
boolean mSelected;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvExample);
    mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/webpage.html");

    mWebView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                View root = getWindow().getDecorView();
                View cabButton = root.findViewById(R.id.action_mode_close_button);

                if (cabButton != null && !mSelected) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Text is now selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mSelected = true;
                } else {
                    mSelected = false;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Text Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }

            return false;
        }
    });
.....
```